# Mysql find dense series gaps

Tags: mysql, series

I have a "sequence" column of a Mysql table with a unique key, this should start from value of 1 to n.

```
create table myTest( id INT, ...,  sequence INT ..)
```

This column should represents a dense serie, so I don't want gaps into it, my question is: **how can I find possible gaps?**

My first idea is to insert into a temporary 1 column table all values from *1* to *max(sequence)* with a loop.

```
create temporary table allvalues( value INT)
```

Then select all elems of this temp table where values are not in myTest table:

```
select value from allvalues where value is not in (select sequence from myTest)
```

Is there any other better/fastest solution?

Comment: pls give different table names in question

Comment: Ok, i rewrited the question with some table names and code. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there will be gaps?

Comment: i would do it the same way

Comment: Not sure, this is what I have to check. I don't know how "sequence" is populated in the table, it can be in any order, but I need to checked if is there some gaps.

Comment: @kamahl ok, but what happends if there are millions of rows? Is this the best way?

Comment: maybe there are better ways.
I still think it is going to be pretty fast.
What you can do is the following:
a.) create a table with all possible integers (it's quite handy for other things too)
b.) put a suitable index on it (range query)
c.) add to your select statement
select value from allvalues where value > (Select min(sequence) from myTest) and value < (select max(sequence) from myTest) and value not in (select sequence from myTest)

Comment: the value is probaboly a primary key and indexed.
so is the table you create.
therefor, everything should be fast.
Also: premature optimization is the root of all evil!

Answer (score 0):

This another idea, this doesn't find **every** gap but only the ending gap in case of contiguous gaps:

```
select m1.sequence-1 from myTest m1
where m1.sequence>1 and not exists
  (select * from myTest m2 where m2.sequence=m1.sequence-1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64f32/1

Comment: yes but that's a solution for another problem and not the one you posted

Comment: Yes of course, but assuming that there should be only few gaps against many rows can be another way to find gap holes and look for numbers around it. I would be nice to know if this solution should be faster compared to the other...